# Как не перезаписывать общий стиль для контрола при установке триггеров?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Есть стиль в общих ресурсах

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    ***
</Style>
```

То есть когда я мержу ресурс к форме, ко всем кнопкам применяется описанный выше стиль. Но если я добавляю к кнопке триггеры, стиль перезаписывается. Выглядит это так

```
<Button>
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                ***
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

То есть кнопка перестает наследовать тот стиль, что описан в смерженном ресурсе. А в ресурсах кнопки я не могу указать для стиля BasedOn, потому что у того стиля нет x:Key, а если задать его, то со всех кнопок во всем проекте слетит этот стиль и придется явно его задавать. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `BasedOn` можно указать тип как ключ, тогда он подхватит дефолтный стиль для этого контрола:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                ***
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Больше информации и примеры есть в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).